What causes <script> tags with type=module to execute out of order?
My first guess would have been "if it gets imported by something else first", but I've seen something that I can't explain with that model.
Here's the scenario:

a bunch of scripts with type=module
there are some libs without type=module - no interdependencies
The first module file is init.js
init.js imports A.js and only imports A.js
A.js imports B.js and only imports B.js
B.js has no imports

The script tags on the index page are:
<script type="module" src="init.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="W.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="X.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="Y.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="Z.js"></script>

Y.js starts executing before init.js. I tested this using the "Script First Statement" event listener breakpoint in my browser.
If I comment out the import for A.js in init.js, then init.js starts executing first as expected.
Neither init.js, A.js, nor B.js contain any asynchronous behavior. Files X.js, Y.jx, and Z.js might but from what I understand this shouldn't matter.
How can I determine the cause of this wild behavior?

well, importing A.js etc requires a network request ... and without knowing the full interdependencies of the modules, the question is, does it matter?

Is it that Y doesn't import anything and is free to load? There's no A or B is files in your example. Without some reproduction it's hard to say. If one script is async, it'll take that much time to load the rest to resolve.

A.js and B.js aren't included in the html, they're imported by init.js

I don't understand why my question was downvoted. I was eventually able to answer my own question using only the information I provided in my question (so I did provide enough information), and it seems perfectly reasonable to me that this behavior would be confusing or not intuitive (import statements share the same behavior as await, despite not having that syntax behind them).

It was because there really is asynchronous behavior in A.js. I wasn't thinking about the fact that the import statement is asynchronous, which is more obvious when you use an import in an expression (await import(...)). The import for B.js starts a network request and then the next <script> tag starts executing.
It seems that imports are hoisted - having a console.log above the import in init.js doesn't make any difference; my "first statement" breakpoint never hits it.
The reason Y.js is executed before W.js is likely the same reason; W.js must also have an import.

Are you sure you don’t have cycles?

Module scripts defer by default and deferred scripts execute in their DOM order: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer

There are no import cycles and the scripts really are being executed in DOM order. However if I set a breakpoint on "Script First Statement" it looks like they're executed in the wrong order (and effectively they are). While deferred scripts execute in their DOM order, the first statement of each script will not necessarily execute in DOM order for the reason I described in my answer.
